# Spherical harmonic expansion with radius

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, spherical-harmonics

I'm having some trouble in computing the spherical harmonic's expansion of a general wave function $\psi(\textbf{x})$ where $\textbf{x}$ is a vector in 3D .

The result on the article I'm working on is the following:
$$\psi_{lm}(r) = r\int d\Omega Z_{lm}(\theta,\phi)\psi(\textbf{x})$$

where $r=|\textbf{x}|$, and $Z_{lm}=\sqrt{2}ReY_{lm}$ if m>0 and $Z_{lm}=\sqrt{2}ImY_{lm}$ if m<0.

I already know that for a general function $f(\theta,\phi)$ I can expand like $$f(\theta,\phi)=\sum_l\sum_mf_{lm}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$$ where $$f_{ml}=\int_{\Omega}f(\theta,\phi)Y_{lm}^*d\Omega$$

but I don't understand the following:

1. $\textbf{Where does that $r$ before the integral come from?}$
2. $\textbf{If I put the integral form of}$ $f_{ml}$ $\textbf{I should get}$ $|Y_{ml}|^2$ $\textbf{so why do I get $Z$?}$